# Haskell parsec error

Tags: haskell, parsec

while learning the parsec tutorial , I tried the fllowing command

```
  print (Parsec.parse (Parsec.many (Parsec.choice [Parsec.letter,Parsec.spaces ,(Parsec.char ','), Parsec.digit])) "" "hello1 , byebye2 ," )
```

and the error in console was [image]

I am not sure how to fix this. How this can be fixed, any ideas??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [hackage](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec-3.1.11/docs/Text-Parsec-Char.html)

```
spaces :: Stream s m Char => ParsecT s u m ()
letter :: Stream s m Char => ParsecT s u m Char
```

so you have parser, that try to give you `Char`s and one, that just drops input and gives you `()`. What should the result be?

You could use

```
space :: Stream s m Char => ParsecT s u m Char
```

or

```
(spaces *> return ' ')
```

instead of just `spaces` depends on the behavior you want.